# Get a current location with maps api on android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I ask, how to create a script, for android, to get a current location with google maps api v2 for android.
Now my scrpt take the location specifying the cordinates.
I post it my java file:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

static final LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(46.493168,11.3306379);
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    try {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                position(TutorialsPoint).title("TutorialsPoint"));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: implement `LocationListener` for that

Comment: First You have to whether you are getting google map view on the screen or not. Then you can the marker. Use getSupportMapFragment() instead of getFragmentManager().

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()` method, type this:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Make your Activity implement `LocationListener`, `onMapReadyCallback` and `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` interfaces. In the methods of that interfaces:

```
onMapReady (from onMapReadyCallbacks):

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        //mapa is your GoogleMap variable
        mapa=map;

    }
```

Doing this, you make sure your map is ready for working.

In onConnected method (from `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` interface) you get your location:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Location lkn=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            gApiClient);
    if(myLocation==null){
        myLocation=new Location("");
    }
    if(lkn!=null){

        myLocation.setLatitude(lkn.getLatitude());
        myLocation.setLongitude(lkn.getLongitude());
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            gApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

And finally, in onLocationChanged (from LocationListener interface):

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //myLocation is a class variable, type Location
    myLocation.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
    myLocation.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

}
```

So, every time the phone have a new location you will receive it in that method.

You will need to implement this two methods too:

```
//call this method in your onCreate()
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    //gApiClient is a class variable, type GoogleApiClient
    gApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Log.i("Map", "Conection failed");
                }
            })
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    gApiClient.connect();
    createLocationRequest();
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```