# Google map show toast at particular location

Tags: android

I want to make a small project that will allow a user to mark attendance only if he is within a particular location with tolerance of 15/20meters. I'm completely confused how to do it. It will be on a button click. 
I have not written any code for the same as I don't know how to do it. I have got the api key as well as have the standard Google map fragment.

Comment: Better you could do is face the problem step by step. First, learn how to get the location of the phone. Then, once you have the location of the phone, learn how to check the distance between two points. And then, do whatever you want to do, if the distance is within that range you set.

Comment: This link could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800711/get-a-current-location-with-maps-api-on-android-studio/33801107#33801107

Comment: You will not get current location accuracy with in a range of 15/20 meters always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get location from google map and compare location like this

```
float radius = 17f;
Location newlocation = new Location("");
newlocation.setLatitude(lattitude); //lattitude is your old location
newlocation.setLongitude(longitude); // longitude is your old location
distance = myLocation.distanceTo(newlocation); //myLocation is your current location
if(distance < radius){

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: know your location coordinates (latitude, longitude) using [Android location services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/index.html)

Step 2: know the "particular location" coordinates

Step 3: calculate the distance between these 2 sets of coordinates (google how to do it)

Step 4: `if (distance < threshold) then { display button }`